# Generalized strong no loop conjecture

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Strong no loop conjecture: Let $A$ be an artin algebra and  $S$ be a simple module in $mod A$, where $mod A$ denotes the right finitely generated module category. If $Ext_{A}^{1}(S,S)\neq 0$, then $pd S=\infty$, where $pd S$ denotes
the projective dimension of $S$.

Question: Is there a ring $A$ which is not an artin algebra, such that for some simple module $S$ with
$Ext_{A}^{1}(S,S)\neq 0$，but $pd S<\infty$?

Comment: $A=k[[t]]$, $S=A/(t)=k$. More generally, $A=$ any local regular ring of dimension $\geq 1$ (commutative) , $S$ its residue field.

Comment: Maybe the question is more interesting when looking only at rings which are close to artin algebras. For example semiprimary rings (rings A with nilpotent Jacobson radical rad(A) and A/rad(A) being semisimple)